# Is OpenGL supposed to set GL_BLEND to false when calling glClear()?

Tags: opengl

I spent ages trying to figure out why the GL_BLEND (alpha blending) state was changing in my program, and I found that OpenGL sets the GL_BLEND state to false after calling glClear to clear the render buffer.

```
GLboolean boolValue;

glEnable(GL_BLEND);
glGetBooleanv(GL_BLEND, &boolValue);
    
assert(boolValue == true); // PASSES

glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);

glGetBooleanv(GL_BLEND, &boolValue);
    
assert(boolValue == true); // FAILS
```

I'm wondering if this is supposed to happen and if it's mentioned in any of the documentation. I'd hate to find out what other states OpenGL changes without knowing about it and spending ages trying to track down why my program is failing.

Edit: I just found out that it does this only on the first call to glClear(). Can anybody verify that this is the proper behavior?

Comment: No. `glClear` doesn't change any state. It just changes the content of the specified buffers.

Comment: @Rabbid76 So this must be a bug on my end, in the drivers or something?

Comment: I don't know. See the Specification [17.4.3 Clearing the Buffers](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL/specs/gl/glspec46.core.pdf#page=545&zoom=100,168,330). Do you get an OpenGL error?

Comment: No, I have the error callback set up and I also call glGetError and I get no errors. This is so weird. Thing is I can't even check if OpenGL does this, because if keep a bool saying that alpha blending is turned off and glClear sets alpha blending to off I won't have any way of knowing if OpenGL did that because they'll compare equal.

Comment: @Rabbid76 I just found out that it only does this on the first call to glClear(). Do you think this is supposed to happen?

Comment: You may want to check the state changes using [apitrace](https://apitrace.github.io).

Comment: Also, which GL implementation and on which OS are you using? Please provide a [mcve].